# Error in if (!all(o)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed R

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I try to create a sentiment analysis system using word2vec and logistic multinomial regression.

For this, I tried to do like the author did here : http://analyzecore.com/2017/02/08/twitter-sentiment-analysis-doc2vec/

Here the R code :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(text2vec)
library(caret)
library(glmnet)
library(ggrepel)

Train_classifier <- read.csv('IRC.csv',header=T, sep=";")
Test_classifier <- read.csv('IRC2.csv',header=T, sep=";")

# select only 4 column of the dataframe

Train <- Train_classifier[, c("Note.Reco", "Raison.Reco", "DATE_SAISIE", "idpart")]
Test <- Test_classifier[, c("Note.Reco", "Raison.Reco", "DATE_SAISIE", "idpart")]

#delete rows with empty value columns
subTrain <- Train[rowSums(Train == '') == 0,]
subTrain$ID <- seq.int(nrow(subTrain))

 subTrain
      DATE_SAISIE    idpart    ID  Raison.Reco  Note.Reco
2      19/03/2014 102853645     1  Good         0
3      19/03/2014   1072309     2  Not good     2
4      19/03/2014    191391     3  very good    9
6      19/03/2014     14529     4  not comment  8
7      19/03/2014 100065501     5  very professional  9
8      19/03/2014 102261392     6  very good  1
9      19/03/2014 102734704     7  good  10
10     19/03/2014   1004397     8  not very good  10

# # replacing class values
subTrain$Note.Reco = ifelse(subTrain$Note.Reco >= 0 & subTrain$Note.Reco <= 4, 0, ifelse(subTrain$Note.Reco >= 5 &
subTrain$Note.Reco <= 6, 1, ifelse(subTrain$Note.Reco >= 7 & subTrain$Note.Reco <= 8, 2, 3)))


subTest <- Test[rowSums(Test == '') == 0,]
subTest$ID <- seq.int(nrow(subTest))

#Data pre processing
#Doc2Vec

prep_fun <- tolower
tok_fun <- word_tokenizer

subTrain[] <- lapply(subTrain, as.character)
it_train <- itoken(subTrain$Raison.Reco, 
                   preprocessor = prep_fun, 
                   tokenizer = tok_fun,
                   ids = subTrain$ID,
                   progressbar = TRUE)



subTest[] <- lapply(subTest, as.character)
it_test <- itoken(subTest$Raison.Reco, 
                   preprocessor = prep_fun, 
                   tokenizer = tok_fun,
                   ids = subTest$ID,
                   progressbar = TRUE)


#creation of vocabulary and term document matrix
  ### fichier  d'apprentissage
vocab_train <- create_vocabulary(it_train)
vectorizer_train <- vocab_vectorizer(vocab_train)
dtm_train <- create_dtm(it_train, vectorizer_train)


  ###  test data



vocab_test <- create_vocabulary(it_test)
vectorizer_test <- vocab_vectorizer(vocab_test)
dtm_test <- create_dtm(it_test, vectorizer_test)

##Define  tf-idf model 

tfidf <- TfIdf$new()
# fit the model to the train data and transform it with the fitted model
dtm_train_tfidf <- fit_transform(dtm_train, tfidf)
dtm_test_tfidf <- fit_transform(dtm_test, tfidf)

glmnet_classifier <- cv.glmnet(x = dtm_train_tfidf,
                               y = subTrain[['Note.Reco']], family = 'multinomial',type.multinomial = "grouped")
```

When I run this code I get this error :

> ```
> > glmnet_classifier <- cv.glmnet(x = dtm_train_tfidf,
> +                                y = subTrain[['Note.Reco']], family = 'multinomial',type.multinomial = "grouped")
> Error in if (!all(o)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
> ```

Any idea please?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

The problem come from this line line @Edward Moseley said in his comment :

```
subTrain[] <- lapply(subTrain, as.character)
```

But when I delete it and I move to this line :

```
it_train <- itoken(subTrain$Raison.Reco, 
                   preprocessor = prep_fun, 
                   tokenizer = tok_fun,
                   ids = subTrain$ID,
                   progressbar = TRUE)
```

I get this error :

```
Error in UseMethod("itoken") : 
  no applicable method for 'itoken' applied to an object of class "factor"




subTrain
> subTrain
      Note.Reco
1             3
2             3
3             2
4             3
5             3
6             1
7             3
8             1
9             2
10            3
11            3
12            3
13            3
14            2
15            2
16            3
17            3
18            2
19            3
20            2
21            2
22            2
23            0
24            0
25            2
26            3
27            3
28            0
29            0
30            2
31            3
32            3
33            3
34            3
35            0
36            1
37            2
38            1
39            3
40            3
41            3
42            1
43            3
44            2
45            3
46            3
47            2
48            3
49            3
50            2
51            1
52            1
53            2
54            3
55            3
56            2
57            2
58            3
59            2
60            1
61            3
62            0
63            2
64            2
65            3
66            0
67            1
68            3
69            2
70            2
71            3
72            2
73            2
74            2
75            3
76            2
77            2
78            3
79            3
80            3
81            3
82            2
83            2
84            1
85            0
86            2
87            0
88            3
89            3
90            3
91            2
92            1
93            2
94            1
95            3
96            3
97            2
98            2
99            3
100           3
101           0
102           2
103           2
104           0
105           2
106           3
107           2
108           2
109           2
110           3
111           3
112           2
113           2
114           2
115           3
116           3
117           2
118           3
119           3
120           3
121           3
122           2
123           3
124           2
125           2
126           0
127           3
128           3
129           0
130           3
131           0
132           1
133           3
134           2
135           0
136           1
137           3
138           1
139           3
140           3
141           3
142           2
143           2
144           3
145           2
146           2
147           3
148           1
149           1
150           3
151           2
152           2
153           3
154           2
155           3
156           2
157           3
158           3
159           3
160           0
161           2
162           1
163           3
164           3
165           1
166           2
167           2
168           3
169           2
170           3
171           3
172           3
173           2
174           2
175           3
176           3
177           0
178           3
179           2
180           3
181           0
182           3
183           3
184           2
185           3
186           3
187           1
188           3
189           1
190           2
191           2
192           3
193           3
194           3
195           2
196           2
197           3
198           2
199           0
200           3
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ... <truncated>
1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ... <truncated>
3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ... <truncated>
4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ... <truncated>
5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ... <truncated>
7
```

I see this "truncated value" in the dataframe, is it normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're introducing problems when you `lapply()`.

Try checking: `(dim(subTrain[['Note.Reco']]) > 0)`

If that evaluates to `TRUE` then you may have a different problem than I describe below.

From the [glmnet github](https://github.com/cran/glmnet) I am seeing: `if (!all(o)) {` as part of `glmnet/R/lognet.R`, (which I am assuming is called by `cv.glmnet`). in the [lognet](https://github.com/cran/glmnet) function we see:

```
27   weights=drop(y%*%rep(1,nc)) 
28   o=weights>0 
29   if(!all(o)){ #subset the data
```

Earlier, on line 2 we see `nc` defined:

```
2   nc=dim(y)
```

The rest of the code depends on the values of `nc`, so I would suggest determining the results of `dim(subTrain[['Note.Reco']])` for starters. You could try accessing those data differently:

```
glmnet_classifier <- cv.glmnet(x = dtm_train_tfidf, y = subTrain$Note.Reco, family = 'multinomial',type.multinomial = "grouped")
```

Also, if you construct a `data.frame` we can copy/paste to work with it will be much easier to debug.

Comment: `> (dim(subTrain[['Note.Reco']]) > 0)
logical(0)`  Thank you for your quick response

Comment: Yes-- try `glmnet_classifier <- cv.glmnet(x = dtm_train_tfidf, y = subTrain$Note.Reco, family = 'multinomial',type.multinomial = "grouped")`

Comment: `Error in if (!all(o)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` same error

Comment: You will need to discover it on your own, but you need to find out how to access `subTrain$Note.Reco` as a vector for input there, you could even try coercing with `as.vector()`.

Comment: Ok, but when  I did `subTrain$Note.Reco` I get the result

Comment: No I mean when I did `subTrain$Note.Reco` I get this result : [1] 3 3 2 3 3 1 3 1 2 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 0 0 2 3 3 0 0 2 3 3 3 3 0 1 2 1 3 3 3 1 3 2 3 3 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 3 3 2 2 3 2 1 3 0 2 2 3 0
  [67] 1 3 2 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 2 1 0 2 0 3 3 3 2 1 2 1 3 3 2 2 3 3 0     But the same prblem

Comment: Maybe: `y = unlist(subTrain$Note.Reco)`, the issue is the way the data is formatted in a list-- try to turn it into a tidy data frame. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html

Comment: Thank youOk , last question , why it must be a vector?

Comment: See page 9 of the glmnet documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf#page9, you will need to adjust the data format to that required by your method.

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of problem too when using glmnet and text2vec. In my case the problem was caused by missing cases. The reason is that the function `all()` called by `cv.glment` doesn't work with missing values. To fix the problem I removed the `NAs` from my data.